# How to not bypass required fields when routerLink

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-router

`routerLink` execute and bypass my submit required fields.

```
      <label for="Användarnamn">Användarnamn och lösenord</label>
      <input type="text" id="Användarnamn" name="Användarnamn" placeholder="Skriv in ditt användarnamn." required>
      <input type="text" id="Lösenord" name="Lösenord" placeholder="Skriv in ditt lösenord." required>
      <input type="submit" routerLink="WAPPEASY">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using routerLink you could use the click event and do check to make sure there are answered before routing away as such

HTML:

```
<form>
  <label for="Användarnamn">Användarnamn och lösenord</label>
  <input type="text" id="Användarnamn" name="Användarnamn" placeholder="Skriv in ditt användarnamn." required>
  <input type="text" id="Lösenord" name="Lösenord" placeholder="Skriv in ditt lösenord." required>
  <input type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">
</form>
```

TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent  {
... WhatEver else in the component

onSubmit(){
   if ((
    <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('Användarnamn')).validity.valid 
    && (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('Lösenord')).validity.valid ) 
    {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('WAPPEASY');
    } 
}
```

[StackBlitz URL to this in action](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xuehxs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)